# c# mutex acquisition issue

Tags: c#, multithreading, mutex

having code like this:

```
void MyMethod() {

   bool acquired = _lockMutex.WaitOne(WAITING_TIME_SPAN);
   if (acquired) {
       Proceed();//everything is ok
   } else {
      actionEnded("Mutex in use!");
   }
}
```

_lockMutex is private static scoped. It seems like when 2 threads at the "same time" tries to acquire mutex when it is free, non of them currently obtain it. Can you explain me why? Thanks

Comment: Seems like? What evidence do you have for this? I'd definitely expect exactly one to acquire it, and you haven't given nearly enough diagnostics to suggest otherwise.

Comment: Do you have a third thread that locks the mutex and "forgets" to release it? That would be a nasty deadlock, but easy to fix.

Comment: @JonSkeet i had a similiar problem once with locks. The debugger showed that 2 threads where waiting for `lock(lockobject)`. The other threads had nothing to do with the lock.

Comment: Ok, got it, it was my fault - in one branch of method I wasn't releasing the mutex. I posted this only to ask if it is possible that sometime non of the competing threads can obtain mutex - obviously stupid question, and the answer is no :). Sorry for bothering.

Comment: A warning about the Mutex (and the lock keyword/Monitor class): Once a thread acquires a Mutex, any additional calls to WaitOne will not block, and you need to call ReleaseMutex the same number of times you call WaitOne (see the Remarks on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx)).  I usually prefer a Semaphore to ensure repeated WaitOne calls will block, since nested thread synchronization calls usually point to other issues in the code.